'Update available for Snap Store' on startup
On login there is a notification panel: 'Update available for Snap Store'
'Quit the app to update it now'
With 2 buttons: 'Show updates' 'Don't remind me again'
If you click 'Don't remind..' it comes back on next reboot.
How do you stop this ?
(Ubuntu 24)

That is an update for "snap" itself, click 'Show updates' - I'd expect to see a way to get it done (e.g. quit snap, and the update taking place). But then this is Snap - might note be that easy. sigh

The easiest way to stop the reminder is by updating Snap Store.
Snaps cannot update while they are running.
Right-click on the dock icon (not the notification), and select Quit.
In 23.04 and newer, the snap will update automatically after Quit.
Older releases of Ubuntu may require sudo snap refresh
When the update is complete, you may receive a notification that you can reopen App Center / Snap Store.


The notification is shown at centre top rather than in the dock area. Right-clicking this produces no effect. If you click 'show updates it goes to the snap store UI and if you click 'Updates' it (currently) only shows the Snap Store  as being available for update (which you cant do as its already running etc...!!). If you do nothing, after a while it goes away by itself. If you right-click the date/time in the top bar you can see the notification again.

Answer edited to clarify and address the comment
